# Why this double for give me undefined propeties javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

my problem is to load images in different divs (called "immaggine"), everything is fine until I get to 5 i

this is my code:

```
function caricaGrid() {
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("immagine");
let stringaIniziale = "assets/image_part_00";
let i = 1;
for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    for(let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        if(i < 10) stringaIniziale += i + ".png";
        else {
            stringaIniziale = "assets/image_part_0";
            stringaIniziale += i + ".png";
        } 
        img.setAttribute("src", stringaIniziale);
        img.setAttribute("data-id", i);
        divs[i++].appendChild(img);
        console.log(stringaIniziale);
        stringaIniziale = "assets/image_part_00";
        
    }
```

}

the problem occurs when the "i" surpasses the 5, below the logs:

```
index.js:20 assets/image_part_001.png
index.js:20 assets/image_part_002.png
index.js:20 assets/image_part_003.png
index.js:20 assets/image_part_004.png
index.js:20 assets/image_part_005.png
index.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
    at caricaGrid (index.js:19)
caricaGrid @ index.js:19
load (asinc)
(anonimo) @ index.js:3
```

if it could help here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cartoleria</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="immagine"></div>
            <div class="immagine"></div>
            <div class="immagine"></div>
            <div class="immagine"></div>
            <div class="immagine"></div>
            <div class="immagine"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

would anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Probably because your `i` starts at 1 instead of 0, so that divs[6] is null. Try initializing `i` to 0. Arrays are 0 indexed

Comment: yes, i would try this, but i think that's correct, thank you very much

Comment: I don't see where i is being incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely have no idea what are you trying to do but here's why you face the error:

The following code will print out from **1** to **36**

```
let i = 1;

for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++){
  for(let k = 0; k<6; k++){
  console.log(i++);
  }
}
```

However based on your html code, you only have **6** divs with the `immagine` class.
which means the last index of your `divs[]` array is going to be **5**.
but the code you wrote will use even the `divs[36]` in the last loop which will cause you the error you've mentioned above.

you can use **K** or **J** for your divs[] based on what you're trying to do (which I dont know!) :

```
for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++){
  for(let k = 0; k<6; k++){
   // ... 

    divs[k].appendChild(img);
    // or
    divs[j].appendChild(img);
   // ...
  }
}
```